# How to execute FreePascal from windows command line as "fpc"

Tags: compiler-construction, pascal, freepascal, windows-console

I've noticed at one place that they was able to call FreePascal compiler as "fpc" from windows command line like:

```
fpc my_program_source.pas
```

How to achieve this? Is it some command that assigns "command => exeFile" ?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom commands in windows Command Prompt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181709/custom-commands-in-windows-command-prompt)

Comment: They might be calling fpc.exe, you can always omit the extension. Your question isn't clear on what's being achieved.

Comment: The directory with fpc.exe has to be included in the PATH environment variable.

Comment: If you run such files windows searches in the PATH

Comment: @SertacAkyuz my question is like superclear ;) see possible duplicate, if my question wasnt clear enaugh for you :)

Comment: @jave - Well, everyone else seem to have understand it. You're right, not for me though. When I saw the comment I thought why would this be a duplicate of that one.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I admit I might have confused you with the Pascal thing, anyway - I then realized that what I want is a more general question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what to do:

1. Find FPC.EXE on your computer. The brute force method would be

   ```
   DIR/S C:\FPC.EXE
   ```
2. Go to the Windoze Control Panel and find System. Under the Advanced settings you should find a PATH variable.
3. Modify PATH so that it looks like

   ```
   WHEVER-IT-WAS:C:\WHAT\EVER\DIRECTORY\YOU\FOUND\FPC\IN
   ```

Add a ":" and your directory.

1. Open a NEW windoze DOS window
2. Do

   FPC
3. If this does not work, type

   ECHO $PATH

Make sure it has the directory you wanted is there. If not, a reboot might be in order.

Comment: I would not call the Win CMD a "DOS window", but thanks for the answer anyway :)

Comment: I would't either but the term I would have used would have gotten me banned from here!