# How to release/publish a .Net Core console application?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, .net-core, package, release

I have a console application that I want to publish for Windows and Ubuntu so end user can install and use it easily. The intended user is *not* a developer but able to use a CLI.

I can generate a release build with `dotnet publish` and zip it.

- What is the release channel then?
- Should I build a `--self-contained` release?
- How is my tool placed into the `$PATH` on the users machine?
- Should I provide an installer for Windows and a PPA for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

In general, a command for publishing console app is `dotnet publish -c Release -r win10-x64`

You should change `win10-x64` by correct rid which belongs to OS such as `linux-x64`, `osx.10.14-x64`

> What is the release channel then?

It depends, if it is running on Window or Linux, it will be .exe file

> Should I build a --self-contained release?

`--self-contained` makes you to isolate any 3rd libraries and a release package. If you aren't sure the host doesn't install any 3rd libraries, so `--self-contained` will help you. Thus a build will be larger than.

> How is my tool placed into the $PATH on the users machine?

Once again, it depends on your target OS. Each OS has a different way to set $PATH. And if you want to custom a cli as `dotnet` or `npm`, check in the link [Custom commands in windows Command Prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181709/custom-commands-in-windows-command-prompt)

> Should I provide an installer for Windows and a PPA for Ubuntu?

If you are DevOps Engineer, so you don't want it because it isn't friendly with CLI. You want only release package.

Comment: It's not about DevOps. Where would I point the end user to get my tool? Why would they user `npm`?

Comment: Oh If you mean how end-user can execute your tool in your computer , so you actually need to have Installer tool with adding @PATH. DotNet Publish just helps you to create .exe that can be runable by cli or double-clicks.