# Execute Custom Command in CMD

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command

I view my git logs in CMD which has a custom format,

```
git log --date=format:'%d %b %I:%M%p' --pretty=format:"%C(Yellow)%h%Creset %cd%Cgreen%d %Creset%s" -10
```

now I have to copy this command every time from my notepad so I was thinking if I can create a custom cmd command that will run the above command.

for eg. I would just write

```
showlog
```

and it will execute my command.

I tried creating a bat file and found this [command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181709/custom-commands-in-windows-command-prompt).

```
start cmd.exe @cmd /k "git log --oneline -10"
```

but it opened a new window I would like this to execute in the same window like other git commands

So I want to know

1. how exactly it is done within the same window?
2. where can I learn more about this?

Comment: Your question as asked is really about .BAT files, but there are questions you could ask about Git here: specifically, about Git aliases, and about `git log` pretty formats. Since you've accepted the .BAT answer I've trimmed off the Git tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use `start` nor `cmd` in your batch file, just the command itself:

```
@echo off
my command and parameters here
```

so for your showlog.bat:

```
@echo off
git log --date=format:'%d %b %I:%M%p' --pretty=format:"%C(Yellow)%h%Creset %cd%Cgreen%d %Creset%s" -10
```

% might be problematic, you might have to escape it with `%%`. While debugging you can remove the `@echo off` to have it echo the command...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of (correct) @anders way for custom cmd-command, you can think about more Git-way of building [Git alias](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases) (use `git showlog`) for the same output: simple, (somehow) faster and more manageable solution.

Something like

```
git config --global alias.showlog 'git log <FULL TAIL OF YOUR COMMAND HERE>'
```